# How to make slash (/) paste with correct Unicode codepoint depending on context?

Tags: symbols, pdftex, unicode, fractions, copy-paste

Unicode offers different characters for the slash:

- U+002F (/) for the ordinary slash
- U+2215 (∕) for the mathematical division operator
- U+2044 (⁄) to designate vulgar fractions

How can I have these automatically paste with the right Unicode codepoint? Some starter code is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input glyphtounicode
  \pdfgentounicode=1
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}

textual: w/o (intended: U+002F)

in an equation: \(12/4 = 3\) (intended: U+2215)

in a vulgar fraction (produced by package \texttt{nicefrac}): 1\nicefrac{1}{2} (intended: U+2044)

\end{document}
```

Note that "-" in math mode already pastes correctly as the "minus sign" (U+2212, "−"), so that is why I suspect that addressing this issue is possible.

*See also my related question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73376/hyphens-at-end-of-line-disappear-upon-pasting-even-if-they-were-present-in-the).*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The three different slashes all use the same glyph name `slash` in the PDF file. Therefore only one mapping can be set via feature `\pdfgentounicode`. The PDF format provides another feature `ActualText` that can be used with package `accsupp`. The example lets the normal slash untouched, it is mapped to U+002F via `\pdfgentounicode`/`glyphtounicode.tex`.
The other two are defined as macros. At some stage macros are necessary for `accsupp`, because it must put some markup in the PDF page contents stream before and after the glyph.

```
\documentclass{article}

\pdfgentounicode=1
\input{glyphtounicode}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% U+2215
\newcommand*{\mathdivide}{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=2215}/\EndAccSupp{}%
  }%
}
% U+2044
\newcommand*{\fractionslash}{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=2044}/\EndAccSupp{}%  
  }%
}

% Patch nice frac macros to insert the right slashes
\makeatletter
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname \@backslashchar @UnitsUglyFrac \endcsname
{/}{\mathdivide}{%
  \@latex@info@no@line{Successful patched \string\@UnitsUglyFrac}%
  }{%
  \@latex@error{Could not patch \string\@UnitsUglyFrac}%
}

\expandafter\patchcmd\csname \@backslashchar @UnitsNiceFrac \endcsname
{/}{\fractionslash}{%
  \expandafter\patchcmd\csname \@backslashchar @UnitsNiceFrac \endcsname
  {/}{\fractionslash}{%
    \@latex@info@no@line{Successful patched \string\@UnitsNiceFrac}%
  }{%
    \@latex@error{Could not patch \string\@UnitsNiceFrac}%
  }%
}{%
  \@latex@error{Could not patch \string\@UnitsNiceFrac}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
/ $a\mathdivide b$
\nicefrac{a}{b} $\nicefrac{a}{b}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The result from copy and paste:

- "/ a∕b a⁄b a⁄b"
- "/ a\u2215b a\u2044b a\u2044b" *(escape notation)*

Comment: I know that this is advertising, but with `xpatch` instead of `etoolbox` you can more simply say `\xpatchcmd{\@UnitsNiceFrac}{...}{...}{...}{...}`

Comment: Thanks. The patch for `nicefrac` is great. I was wondering whether there is a way to simply write `/` instead of defining a new macro `\mathdivide` using `accsupp`. The reason I suspect such a solution could be possible is that the hyphen-minus is somehow being treated in two different ways by (La)TeX depending on the mode, leading to two different pastable Unicode characters in the output. So there might be a way to patch/amend TeX internals?

Comment: The hyphen and minus sign are different glyphs usually (the minus sign is longer).

Comment: Yes -- What I mean is that I can input the same character "hyphen-minus" (`-`) in the source; when it is in text mode it will paste as the "hyphen-minus", but when it is in math mode it will paste as the "minus sign". That means that LaTeX has a mechanism by which it treats the same input character in a way that leads to two different, context-dependent output pastings. The fact that both slashes look the same (assuming that they do) shouldn't be an obstacle *in theory*: perhaps one can define two characters generated by textmode-`/` and mathmode-`/` that look the same but paste differently.

Comment: TeX uses math fonts in math. It depends on the fonts you are using. With standard setting you get for `-` in the text font the glyph `hyphen` and glyph `minus` in the math font. But for `/` you get in both cases the glyph `slash`.

Comment: Okay, I see - so that sounds like it's not easy to change.