# Hyphens at end of line disappear upon pasting, even if they were present in the input

Tags: pdftex, unicode, hyphenation, copy-paste

When I paste text from pdflatex output, there are two things about hyphens that I would like to change:

- Hyphens paste as "hyphen-minus" (U+002D, "-"), but I would prefer the newer Unicode character "hyphen" (U+2010, "‐"), used for textual hyphens.
- Line-breaking hyphens always disappear. This is good if there was no hyphen in the input, but when a word such as "ice-cream" breaks over a line, it would be nice to keep the hyphen.

Note that line-final en-dashes paste correctly. Here is some code illustrating the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input glyphtounicode
  \pdfgentounicode=1
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Hello World, this is dummy text intended to cause a line break: I love line-breaking. Now a long word without an original hyphen: antidisestablishmentarianism. Some dummy text for getting the desired line breaks; some dummy text for getting the desired line breaks.

Compound adjective (with en-dash): World\ War\ II--related, World\ War\ II--related, World\ War\ II--related.

\end{document}
```

With this code, the pasting behavior is as follows: the hyphen in "line-breaking" disappears (not desired), the hyphen for the line-breaking of "antidisestablishmentarianism" disappears (desired), and the en-dash remains (desired). (Just in case it matters, I'm using Adobe Reader X (version 10.1.4) on Windows 7.)

**Is there an easy way to address these two points?** An ideal solution won't make use of new commands (say, using `accsupp`, as great as this package is) but will modify the way (La)TeX deals with `-` in its input source code. Also a solution ideally applies the specialized hyphen character (U+2010) conservatively: for example hyphens in URLs are ordinarily simple hyphen-minuses. (Yep, I know that all this might be quite tricky to implement.)

*See also my related question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73373/how-to-make-slash-paste-with-correct-unicode-codepoint-depending-on-context).*

Comment: with evince 3.4.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 both hyphens are copied as `hyphen-minus` (`u+002D`) and the en-dash is copied as it is (`u+2013`)

Comment: See this question for a starting point. The general idea is to make `-` an _active character_, then you can redefine its behavior to whatever you want. It might require some TeX wizardry to code all of this correctly. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5737/changing-to-textendash

Comment: A link to a similar question: [Remove hyphen from word spanning two lines in text copied from a pdf file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60682/14996)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a first step towards an answer, which can hopefully be made better with the help of others (or can motivate those in the know to post a better answer):

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{glyphtounicode}
  \pdfgentounicode=1
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\usepackage{url}

\let\originalhyphen-


\makeatletter
\newcount\vh@hyphens


\def\vh@mkhyphens#1\originalhyphen
{%
  \ifnum#1>\z@
    \expandafter\vh@mkhyphens\number\numexpr#1-\@ne\relax\originalhyphen
  \fi
  \originalhyphen
}


\catcode`\-=\active
\DeclareRobustCommand\visiblehyphen
{%
  \ifmmode
    \originalhyphen
   \else
    \expandafter\@visiblehyphen
  \fi
}

\newcommand\@visiblehyphen
{%
  \@ifnextchar-{\global\advance\vh@hyphens\@ne}\@@visiblehyphen
}

\newcommand\@@visiblehyphen
{%
  \ifnum\vh@hyphens>\z@
    \expandafter\vh@mkhyphens\number\vh@hyphens\originalhyphen
    \global\vh@hyphens\z@
   \else
    \mbox{\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=200B2010}\originalhyphen\EndAccSupp{}}\hskip\z@%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\let-\visiblehyphen


\begin{document}

Hello World, this is dummy text intended to cause a line break: I love line-breaking. Now a long word without an original hyphen: antidisestablishmentarianism. Some dummy text for getting the desired line breaks; some dummy text for getting the desired line breaks.

Compound adjective (with en-dash): 
World\ War\ II--related, World\ War\ II--related, World\ War\
II--related.

Math mode 
\[a^2-b^2\]

Url
\begin{center}
  \url{http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

It has the following drawbacks:

1. It uses the `accsupp` package, which you don't want. But I can't imagine how to achieve this result otherwise.
2. It seems that at least on Linux, `acroread` suppresses *any* kind of hyphen inside of a word, so u+2010 as well as u+2011 both disappear. To show that the technique works at all, I now used a zero-width space before the hyphen (u+200B), which strangely turns into a regular space here upon pasting, but maybe you can find something better by experimentation.
3. Redefining a character like `-` in an unexpandable way has a lot of side effects, for instance inside `\numexpr` or `\dimexpr`. Maybe it would be better to use a dedicated command for an explicit hyphen inside text instead. Or to somehow restrict the redefinition of `-` to the document text.

Here's the pasted text:

```
Hello World, this is dummy text intended to cause a line break: I love line ‐
breaking. Now a long word without an original hyphen: antidisestablishmentarianism.
Some dummy text for getting the desired line breaks; some dummy
text for getting the desired line breaks.
Compound adjective (with en ‐dash): World War II–related, World War II–
related, World War II–related.
Math mode
a2 − b2
Url
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends
```

Comment: Re 1: The `accsupp` package is totally fine. I just meant that the user should be able to type ordinary hyphen-minuses (`-`) that are contextually resolved as much as possible, with the user needing to rely on *new-**commands**-that-use-`accsupp`* as little as possible. Re 3: You might be right. I'm wondering about the most unobtrusive way to do this. I suppose someone else creative can refine your answer (or create a new one). Thanks!